# If the number $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ exists, can I assert that there is some function $F$ such that $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification, soft-question

I'm trying to prove the Evaluation Theorem  ( FTC, part 2)  , i.e.  $\int_a^b f(x)dx = G(b)-G(a)$ with $G'=f$.

Apparently, I need as a premise the assertion :

> If $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ exists,  there is some function
> $F$ such that $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$

***Can I condidently use such a premise? Under what conditions is it valid?***

With this premise, the proof may be :

(1) Suppose there is some number $A$ such that :  $A = \int_a^b f(x)dx$.

(2) ***By the above premise***, there is some function $F$ such that : $F(x)= \int_a^x f(t)dt$

(3) By the $FTC$ , Part $1$ , $F'=f$ ( $F$ is a primitive of $f$).

(4)  Let $G$ be any primitive of $f$ : $G(x)= F(x)+C$ , or equivalently $ F(x)= G(x)-C$.

(5) By the definition of $F$ , $F(a)= 0$.

(6) By the defnition of $F$, $A= \int_a^b f(x)dx = F(b)= F(b)-0 = F(b)-F(a) $.

(7) Applying (4) to (6) we get :

$$A= \int_a^b f(x)dx = [G(b)-C ] - [G(a) -C]$$

$$A= \int_a^b f(x)dx = G(b)-C  - G(a) + C$$

(8) Conclusion :

$$\forall A, \space A=\int_a^b f(x)dx \implies A = G(b)-G(a) $$

$$\text {for some G such that } G'= f.$$

Comment: The theorem to prove: If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is also integrable on $[a,x]$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.  (These could be "Riemann" or "Lebesgue".)

Comment: For Lebesgue integration you need an absolutely continuous function for the existence of primitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that

> If $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ exists,  there is some function
> $F$ such that $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$

is trivial as if $f$ in integrable (Lebesgue or Riemann) on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is integrable on any interval $[a, c]$ with $a \lt c \lt b$.

However, you're missing a fundamental hypothesis of the usual Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, which is that $f$ has to be continuous.

Comment: Thanks ! What  aim at is precisely to get a better understanding of the hypoheses of the FTC.

Comment: How is say the logarithmic integral function [0,u] where $u>2$ classified? This can be proved to exist when the $u$ spans $1$, but not when $u=1$. Presumably it is either Lebesgue or Riemann Integrable or not continuous?